# Create Sub Domain - Apache Virtual Host on LocalHost

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, subdomain

My Question in the title may be wrong, but I have no other Idea how to word it. (Experts please help with this?).

Basically sub domains works on my Development Machine when I got to URL `http://subdomain.localhost`. What I am trying to achieve is loading that same website using `http://subdomain.jacques`. `jacques` being the name of my computer.

This is what I have in my `hosts` file in windows.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
localhost   localhost
jacques localhost

subdomain.127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost
subdomain.localhost subdomain.localhost
subdomain.jacques   subdomain.localhost
```

This is what I have in the `vhosts.conf` file.

```
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "c:\web"

<VirtualHost jacques:80 jacques *:80>
    <Directory "c:\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:\web"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain.jacques *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.localhost
    ServerName subdomain.jacques
    ServerAlias subdomain.localhost
    ServerAlias subdomain.jacques
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\subdomain"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\subdomain">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**What I have tried from reading the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) on the Apache website:**

- Adding the PC name to the `<VirtualHost>` tag.
- Adding another `ServerName`/`ServerAlias` to the Virtual Host
- Adding entries into the `hosts` file in Windows

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, so even if you can answer the question, please point me in the right direction.

**System Details**

- **OS**: Windows 10
- **Apache Version**: 2.4
- **PHP Version**: 5.4 (Not sure if this is useful or even relevant.)
- **Apache Install Path** `c:\amp\apache`
- **PHP Install Path** `c:\amp\php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I have in my hosts file in windows.

this is wrong format. Must be - "ip address fqdn"

```
127.0.0.1 localhost jacques subdomain.localhost subdomain.jacques
```

As for virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "c:\web"

    <Directory "c:\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.localhost
    ServerAlias subdomain.jacques

    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\subdomain"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\subdomain">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can use domain (and any subdomain) lvh.me for testing purpose. As it resolves to 127.0.0.1. So there is no need to edit hosts file

```
# host lvh.me
lvh.me has address 127.0.0.1
lvh.me mail is handled by 10 mail.lvh.me.

# host subdomain.lvh.me
subdomain.lvh.me has address 127.0.0.1
```